# Why empty stylesheet returns text from XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

Could you explain why empty stylesheet returns TEXT value?
The stylesheet is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the test file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TEST>
    <ABC>
        <a>ABC</a>
        <b>BCD</b>
        <c>CDE</c>
    </ABC>
</TEST>
```

Returns TEXT value:

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
```

It is simplified example, this case happens when the test file doesn't fit xsl:template match= value inside the stylesheet.
Would be great to understand xslt behavior in that scenario.